# Angular JS not updating view on nested object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using the excellent [AngularJS Rails Resources](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) and with one object - which has deep nested objects in turn - when I update some of its properties, the updated property does not show on the template until I reload the page.

Let start from the beginning: here's my object:

```
    var invoice = Invoice.get($stateParams.invoiceId).then(function (result) {
      $scope.invoice = result;
    });
```

And here's how I open my modal to edit the values:

```
$scope.openEdit = function (edit) {
  $scope.editModal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'editModalContent.html',
    controller: 'InvoiceShowController',
    size: 'lg'
  });
  $scope.editModal.result.then(function(select) {
  });
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
  $scope.$close();
};

$scope.ok = function () {
  $scope.invoice.update().then(function (result) {
    $scope.cancel();
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

In my view I have the following:

```
...
<li>{{invoice.trading_details.trading_name}}</li>
<li>{{invoice.trading_details.trading_address_1}}</li>
...
```

In the modal body I have the following:

```
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Trading Name</label>
      <input ng-model="invoice.trading_details.trading_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Trading Address Line 2</label>
      <input ng-model="invoice.trading_details.trading_address_1" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
    </div>
    ...
```

So when I edit the properties in the modal and console the object, the changes are there. When I save and get the result back, the changes are there, but for whatever reason the view is not updating.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: My whole [controller](http://pastebin.com/QAPSMXG7)**

Comment: I have a feeling that you have two different `invoice` objects on two different scopes. Could you try logging out $scope.$id in both view and modal?

Comment: @BroiSatse you're right. The ids are different. In this case, how can I pass the same `$scope` to the modal? One thing that beats me is in the Angular Bootstrap example why is there a need for two controllers?

Comment: Well, to be honest it doesn't prove anything. Modal is operating within its own scope which is a child of your view scope. This however means that your modal scope invoice is exactly some object  as your view invoice unless you overridden it in your controller. Do you mind posting your InvoiceShowController as well?

Comment: I've added my controller as a pastebin as its a bit big.

Comment: Ok, as expected you have created invoice object on a child scope within your controller. That causes that you have two completely separate objects representing same data and also causing unnecessary backend call. I'll post an answer in a second.

Comment: Actually let's experiment a little bit. Try removing controller from the $modal.open function and instead add `scope: $scope`

Comment: Ha! That seems to have partially done the trick as now the property is being update throughout, however the `$scope.$close` or `$scope.calcel()` function that was being used to close the modal programmatically is not longer working. I guess that's definitely a minor issue compared to the one before though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89711/discussion-between-broisatse-and-wagnermatosuk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `resolve` setting.  It passing data to your modal.

```
$scope.openEdit = function (edit) {
   $scope.editModal = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'editModalContent.html',
      controller: 'InvoiceShowController',
      size: 'lg',
      //notice a function is returning the data
      resolve: {
         invoice: function(){
             return  $scope.invoice;
         }
      }
  });
 };
```

*EDIT*
Link to Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IJvdBJrJngsNYaG39Gfh?p=preview

Notice how the resolve creates an instance *invoice* that is passed into the editCtrl.

**UPDATE**
You can also do

```
   $scope.editModal = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'editModalContent.html',
      controller: 'InvoiceShowController',
      size: 'lg',
      //notice a function is returning the data
      resolve: {
         invoice: function(){
             return  Invoice.get($stateParams.invoiceId);
         }
      }
  });
```

...because the `resolve` can process a promise.

Comment: Can you put {{invoice}} in your modal to see if it is assigned anything?

Comment: It is. It seems to be the whole invoice object.